# Environment variables and PHP

Tags: environment-variables, php

I have an ubuntu server with a handful of custom environment variables set in /etc/environment as per the [ubuntu community recommendation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables)

When I use php from the command line I can use php's `getenv()` function to access this variables.

Also, if I run `phpinfo()` from the command line I see all of my variables in the ENVIRONMENT section.

However, when trying to access the same data inside processes being run by php5-fpm this data is not available.  All I can see in the ENVIRONMENT section of `phpinfo()` is:

```
USER    www-data
HOME    /var/www
```

I know the command line uses this ini:

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

And fpm uses:

```
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

I've not managed to find any differences between the two that would explain why the ENV variables are not coming through in both.

Also if run:

```
sudo su www-data
```

and then echo the environment variables I am expecting they are indeed available to the www-data user.

What do I need to do to get my environment variables into the php processes run by fpm?

Comment: Have you checked your php-fpm process is running under the correct user?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It turns out that you have to explicitly set the ENV vars in the php-fpm.conf

Here's an example:

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log

[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chdir = /
env[MY_ENV_VAR_1] = 'value1'
env[MY_ENV_VAR_2] = 'value2'
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm running php-fpm under the user who set the environment variable correctly. but I set the 'php-fpm.conf' with 'env[MY_ENV_1]=$MYENV1' which use the dollar sign. But I can read the $MYENV1. phpinfo() print out 'no value'. But when I run in CLI. I can read the correct value.

Comment: env[myvariable] worked when I placed it in the /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf file. the php-fpm.conf didn't work.

Answer (score 15):

**1. Setting environment variables automatically in php-fpm.conf**

```
clear_env = no
```

**2. Setting environment variables manually in php-fpm.conf**

```
env[MY_ENV_VAR_1] = 'value1'
env[MY_ENV_VAR_2] = 'value2'
```

**! Both methods are described in php-fpm.conf:**

> Clear environment in FPM workers Prevents arbitrary environment
>   variables from reaching FPM worker processes by clearing the
>   environment in workers before env vars specified in this pool
>   configuration are added. Setting to "no" will make all environment
>   variables available to PHP code via getenv(), $_ENV and $_SERVER.
>   Default Value: yes

```
clear_env = no
```

> Pass environment variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH. All $VARIABLEs are
>   taken from the current environment. Default Value: clean env

```
env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

I found solution in this [github discussion](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/74) .

Comment: in my case clear_env option doesn't even exist in php 5.3.10, but settings var like you've showed did a trick!

Comment: I would also add that in the case your `php-fpm` is started by `systemd` you may need at first to point it where to get env vars. E.g. in `/lib/systemd/system/php7.2-fpm.service` set `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment`

Comment: env[MYVAR] = $HOSTNAME did not work for me. Inside PHP, MYVAR got resolved to nothing while 'echo $HOSTNAME' shows a valid hostname. any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you run the php-fpm. The process not load the environment.
You can load it in the startup script.
My php-fpm is install by apt-get.
So modify the

> /etc/init.d/php5-fpm

and add (beware the space between the dot and the slash)

> . /etc/profile

and modify the /etc/profile to add

> . /home/user/env.sh

In the env.sh. You can `export` the environment whatever you need.

Then modify

> php-fpm.conf

add `env[MY_ENV_VAR_1] = 'value1'`  under the `[www]` section.
Last. restart the php-fpm. You'll get the environment load by the fpm.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the answers above, I was running `php-fpm7` and `nginx` in an `alpine:3.8` docker container. The problem that I faced was the env variables of `USER myuser` was not getting copied into the `USER root`

My entrypoint for docker was

```
sudo nginx  # Runs nginx as daemon
sudo php-fpm7 -F -O  # Runs php-fpm7 in foreground
```

The solution for this was

```
sudo -E nginx
sudo -E php-fpm7 -F -O
```

`-E` option of sudo copies all env variables of current user to the root

Of course, your `php-fpm.d/www.conf` file should have `clear_env=no`

And FYI, if you're using a daemon service like `supervisord` they have their own settings to copy the env. For example, `supervisord` has setting called `copy_env=True`