# What is the PHP7 version of $_SERVER['HOME']

Tags: php, server, php-7

Recently, I have installed a new Ubuntu server which incorporates PHP7. Previously, on PHP5.3 (or it may have been a later version of PHP5, I could use `$_SERVER['HOME']` which returned the home path of the server (i.e. /var/www/). However, this is not possible in PHP7 as $_SERVER['HOME'] is no more.

If I have a site which has a document root of /var/www//httpdocs, how do I get the /var/www/ part. I can not hard code it as my test server (a Synology NAS) does not use PHP7 and can not be upgraded to PHP7 and thus, I need to use a variable that is constant for PHP5 and PHP7 which return the same result to forumate the same result as $_SERVER['HOME'] did in PHP5.

I tried using `$_ENV['HOME']` but this appears to print nothing from my system when a simple `die($_ENV['HOME']);` is executed.

Can someone put me out of my misery please?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note: `$_SERVER["HOME"]` was never a standard PHP provided header. It's probably because the webserver is also a different version now. Just do a `print_r($_SERVER)` you'll find what you need.

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos. I did try that but the only one I could see was the document root but I need it to be the PARENT of the document root. Maybe I need to look at "string dirname ( string $path [, int $levels = 1 ] );". Would you concur on that?

Comment: Well, first you can try`getenv("HOME")` and in the worse case `exec("echo ~")` to try to get it a bit more reliable. If not then what you're suggesting would work assuming you maintain a similar setup in all environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks to @apokryfos, I have sorted the issue. I perhaps should have mention I wanted to include a file outside of the document root (oops, my bad).

The getenv('HOME') for some unknown reason returns an empty string on my server, but the method I used to overcome this was to use the dirname option.

The final result was:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],1)."/includes");
```

Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful. I've recently upgraded from PHP-7.0 to PHP-7.1 and ran into the same issue. The `$_SERVER["HOME"]` was no longer set. While I wasn't really using it for anything I did find it a bit curious so this is what I did to fix it: Install and enable PHP-7.1-FPM and disable the PHP-7.1 apache2 mod.

```
a2dismod php7.1 
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
a2enconf php7.1-fpm
service apache2 restart
```

The idea should be similar for version 7.0

Though I didn't need to do the next step, the question [Environment variables and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428872/environment-variables-and-php) seems to suggest setting the environment variable manually may be required as well.

Hope it helps.